# Does Redshirts Deluxe fix the stalemate issues of the original game?

Tags: untagged

It took two hours to end the game originally, and by that point everyone was just glad to have finished. Does Redshirts Deluxe, the new version of [Redshirts](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/120426/redshirts), fix any of the stalemate issues experienced in the base game or is it still stuck in an endless loop of attempting to end the game?  Is the new expansion worth getting to make the base game playable?

Comment: Michael Campbell raised a good question in his "answer": What was causing your stalemates? If you described that, then the community may have an easier time determining whether your specific case was addressed by the expansion.

Answer (score 0):

The new version clarified a lot of the rules, and fixed a lot of problems with the game including removing "play anytime" from cards.

If you were unable to end the game because people were playing too many cards out of turn, then the removal of the "play anytime" rule from all the cards should reduce this type of stalemate. It is still possible to play cards in response to a mission attempt, but the sequence is more clearly defined, as is when cards can be played.

The new version of the rules can be found here:
http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/84529/redshirts-deluxe-edition-rules

Comment: This answer demonstrates neither an understanding of what was causing the stalemates nor an understanding of how the deluxe edition addressed those issues.

Comment: @Rainbolt the question demonstrates no explanation of what was causing stalemates for the OP, so how is anyone short of a mind reader supposed to answer those details?

Comment: Pretty much. Can't be more specific unless the question is more specific.

Comment: @atk If Michael needed more information to answer the question, he should have requested that in the comments and either downvoted or voted to close the question as unclear. It looks like someone else has done that, and I will follow suit.

Comment: The stalemate was caused in a six player game, by out of turn card play mechanic (causing mission success) and by continuously giving crew members back and forth around the table.  The one play we had lasted 2 hours before everyone rage quit.